# How to find a Excel cell based on interior color RBG in Win32Com (Python)?

Tags: python, excel

1. I need to find a cell in Excel based on the interior color of the cell. I tried the below code but get the error "name RBG is not defined"

```
import win32com.client as w3c
testfile='C:\Desktop\Test.xlsm'
 
xl=w3c.DispatchEx("Excel.Application")
 
wb3=xl.Workbooks.Open(Filename=testfile, ReadOnly=False, UpdateLinks=0, IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended=True)
test_sht=wb3.Worksheets('Sheet1')
 

# if test_sht.cells(71,2).Interior.ColorIndex==35: 
if test_sht.Cells(71, 2).Interior.Color == RBG (155, 244, 255):
    print("OK")
 
else:
    print("Not OK")
```

2. Alternatively, I can try using colorindex

```
if test_sht.cells(71,2).Interior.ColorIndex==35:
```

But how do I find the equivalent color index for RBG (155, 244, 255)?

Thank you

Comment: `name RGB is not defined` couldn't realistically be much clearer... if `RGB` is a function, you need to define or import it somewhere, or Python has no way of knowing what you're attempting to call.

Comment: @kungphu. Hi, 1) So how do I import RGB? or instead how do I find the color index for my color in RGB? Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no clue where that function call came from. If it's something you found in an example or tutorial, that should have either the import statement or a reference to the library that should let you find that information.